# Asp .Net Core and Copying JS functions in every page

Tags: javascript

Someone told me to not put JS functions that i need to use several times like datepicker for example cause it slows pages down. However this person did not explain to me why.

My question is, on one of my applications I have different forms where there's

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Artigo.DataPrevistaAplicacao" class="control-label"></label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Artigo.DataPrevistaAplicacao, "dd-MM-yyyy", new { @class = "datepicker" })
            <span asp-validation-for="Artigo.DataPrevistaAplicacao" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then in every page i add JS function

```
<script src="~/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $('.datepicker').datepicker();

</script>
```

what's so bad about doing this? Besides being a nuisance if i have to change each one by one?

Comment: why you put it in every page you can put it only in main layout view ?

Comment: Because by that logic i would just put everything in main layout view even if i'm not using aall the time and that slows down each http request

Comment: you should put only the most common used scripts in main layout and include its script files in ScriptBundle which will enhance the performance and won't make huge slow down in your site